# How do I merge identical adjacent rows with dynamic row spans in Ag-Grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-validation

Most examples of rowspanning I have seen involve hard-coded values.

How would I create row-spans dynamically based on the column values? Specifically, I'd like to dynamically merge all adjacent identical rows into one cell, to get a result such as this:

[Ag-Grid - Only Date rows are to be span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB7lK.jpg)

Can the function logic to define a row-span access the values from other rows? Can it do so relative to itself (e.g. next row, prev row)?

Comment: Please read the documentation for rowspan : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-spanning/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While defining your column definitions, you can specify the row span of each column.

For example this will specify 5 rows merged

```
colDef = {
    headerName: "Country",
    field: "country",
    rowSpan: 5
}
```

Also you can have it as a function to be more dynamic

```
colDef = {
    headerName: "Country",
    field: "country",
    rowSpan: function(params) {
        return params.data.country==='Russia' ? 2 : 1;
    }
}
```

This will specify 2 merged rows if the country is Russia and 1 for everything else. This is taken from AG-Grid documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-spanning/).

I suggest reading more on the row span in the documentation. It explains it well.

Comment: Yup, I saw this documentation before raising the question. I appreciate your answer is fine. I need row span dynamic way. Can you please suggest for dynamic way.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, since it's a function you can have it return a different row span based on your logic.

Comment: I think what he was trying to ask was how to, for example, merge two cells after the ag-grid is loaded and the cells are displayed.

Comment: How can rowSpan when two country is same not just Russia?